# Suppose there are $n$ cities, and roads are being built between these cities (randomly). What is the smallest $n$ such that all pairs are connected?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there are 2020 cities, and $n$ roads are being built between these cities (randomly). What is the smallest $n$ such that all pairs of cities are connected either directly by a road, or indirectly by roads going through other cities?

For this problem, I found the 'worst-case' scenario, where one city is disconnected, and all other cities are completely connected by roads. This leaves us with ${2020 \choose 2}$. We simply add $1$ more road to connect all cities. However, I'm not sure how to prove that all cities, no matter the configuration, are connected for all $n \ge {(n-1) \choose 2}+1$ roads. Can anyone help?

Comment: You can always draw an open chain connection between these cities: therefore the number is $n-1$...

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you means. How many roads are built? Is it the same as $n$ the number of cities?

Comment: Suppose there are at least two disconnected pieces, containing $k$ and $n-k$ cities. How many roads can be built then?

Comment: @BimoAdityarahman I have edited the problem. I was slightly confused myself as to what $n$ is. It should be ok now

Comment: @Mathsexplorer: You have a typo: leaving just one city disconnected and maximally connecting all of the other cities requires $\binom{2019}2=2\,037\,171$ roads, not $\binom{2020}2$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that we remove enough roads to disconnect the network; then there is a city $c$ from which it is not possible to reach every other city. Let $C$ be the set of all cities that are accessible from $c$ (including $c$ itself), and let $D$ be the set of all cities that are inaccessible from $c$. We may assume that $|C|\le|D|=2020-|C|$ and hence that $|C|\le 1010$. (If not, replace $c$ by one of the cities in $D$: from that city one can reach at most the cities in $D$.)

There are no roads between any city in $C$ and any city in $D$, so at least $|C|\cdot|D|$ roads must be missing. Let $m=|C|$; then $|D|=2020-m$, so $$|C|\cdot|D|=m(2020-m)\,,$$ and we want to minimize this function of $m$ on the set $\{1,2,\ldots,1010\}$.

The graph of $y=x(2020-x)$ is a parabola opening down and crossing the $x$-axis at $0$ and $2020$, so the minimum value of $f(x)=x(2020-x)$ on the closed interval $[1,2019]$ is attained at $x=1$ and $x=2019$. Only the first of these is a possible value of $m$, so the smallest value of $m(2020-m)$ is attained when $m=1$, i.e., when $c$ is disconnected from all of the other cities, and the other $2019$ cities are maximally connected.